# Is it Possible to Add Video Using Alt Text on Shopify Product Page

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I was trying to insert video via alt text for images on product page but still stuck. I'm using Grid Theme and did play around the the template. Here is sample of video I want to add via alt text. 
https://www.beardbrand.com/collections/utility-balm/products/tree-ranger-utility-beard-balm

I've tried on different free themes on shopify but still didn't work. This is the code where I tried to test on the current theme.

```
{% if image.alt contains 'youtube' %}

<iframe width="500px" height="500px" src="{{image.alt}} 
autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> 
 </iframe>
 {% else %}

<a href="{{ image.src | img_url: product_image_size, scale: 
product_image_scale }}" class="text-link product-single__thumbnail 
product-single__thumbnail--{{ section.id }}"
{% if enable_zoom %}data-zoom="{{ image.src | img_url: 
 product_image_zoom_size, scale: product_image_scale }}"{% endif %}>

<img class="product-single__thumbnail-image" src="{{ image.src | 
img_url: product_thumb_size, scale: product_image_scale }}" alt="{{ 
image.alt | escape }}">
</a>
{% endif %}
```

I also tried using this code below:

```
<div id="product-flexslider" class="flexslider product_gallery 
product-{{product.id }}-gallery 
{% if product-images == blank %}product_slider
{% endif %} 
 {% if settings.product_thumbs == false %}animated fadeInUp {% endif %}">
   <ul class="slides">
    {% for image in product.images %}
    <li data-thumb="{{ image | product_img_url: '1024x1024' }}" 
    data-title="{% if image.alt contains 'youtube' or image.alt 
    contains 'vimeo' %}{{ product.title }}
   {% else %}
   {{ image.alt | escape }}{% endif %}">
    {% if image.alt contains 'youtube' or image.alt contains 'vimeo' %}
    {% assign src = image.alt | split: 'src="' %}
    {% assign src = src[1] | split: '"' | first %}

    {% if src contains '?' %}
    {% assign src = src | append: '&amp;autoplay=1' %}
    {% else %}
    {% assign src = src | append: '?autoplay=1' %}
    {% endif %}

  <div class="video-container {% if image.alt contains 'vimeo' %}
  vimeo{% else %}
  youtube{% endif %}">
  <div>
  <a href="{{ src }}" title="{{ product.title | escape }}">
        {{ image.alt }}
    </a>
      </div>
  </div>
    {% else %}
  <a href="{{ image | product_img_url: 'master' }}" 
   title="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
   <img  src="{{ image | product_img_url: '1024x1024' }}" 
   alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}"/>
    </a>
    {% endif %}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is the liquid code for the start of product image.

```
  <div class="product-images
  {% if images_layout == 'masonry' %}
    product-images-masonry
    product-images-masonry-{{ product.images.size }}
  {% endif %}"
  {% if images_layout == 'masonry' and product.images.size > 1 %}
  data-masonry-gallery
  {% endif %}>
  {% if images_layout == 'masonry' and product.images.size > 1 %}
  <div class="product-image-masonry-sizer" data-masonry-image-sizer> 
  </div>
  {% endif %}

  {% if images_layout == 'slideshow' %}
  <div class="product-main-image">
  {% assign main_image = variant.image | 
  default: product.featured_image %}
    {% assign main_image_alt = product.title %} 
    {% if main_image.alt != blank %}
      {% assign main_image_alt = main_image.alt %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if main_image != blank %}
      {% capture attr %}
        data-image-id="{{ main_image.id }}"
        data-product-main-image
      {% endcapture %}

      {%
        include 'rimg',
        img: main_image,
        attr: 'data-product-main-image',
        lazy: lazy,
        size: '1400x',
        attr: attr
      %}
    {% else %}
      {{ 'product-1' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
    {% endif %}

    {% if enable_zoom %}
      <div class="product-zoom"></div>
    {% endif %}

  </div>

   {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
   <div class="product-thumbnails-outer-wrapper">
      {% if product.images.size > 4 %}
     <span class="product-thumbnails-navigation-previous">&#xe601;</span>
      {% endif %}

     <div class="product-thumbnails-wrapper">
     <div class="product-thumbnails 
     {% if product.images.size > 4 %}has-side-scroll{% endif %}">
       {% for image in product.images %}
     <div class="product-thumbnail 
     {% if mainImage == image %}active{% endif %}">
              {% capture attr %}
                data-image-id="{{ image.id }}"
              {% endcapture %}
              {%
                include 'rimg',
                img: image,
                size: '115x',
                attr: attr,
                lazy: lazy
              %} 
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>

      {% if product.images.size > 4 %}
        <span class="product-thumbnails-navigation-next">&#xe600;</span>
      {% endif %}

     </div>

  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  {%- for image in product.images -%}
    {% assign use_large_image = false %}
    {% if product.images.size == 2 %}
      {% assign use_large_image = true %}
    {% elsif forloop.first and use_masonry %}
      {% assign use_large_image = true %}
    {% endif %}

    {% assign image_alt = product.title %} 
    {% if image.alt != blank %} 
    {% assign image_alt = image.alt %}
       {% endif %}

    <div class="product-image {% if use_large_image %}product-image-wide{% endif %}">
      {%
        include 'rimg',
        img: image,
        size: '575x',
        lazy: lazy,
        data-image-id: image.id
      %}
    </div>
  {%- else -%}
    <div class="product-image {% if use_large_image %}product-image-wide{% endif %}">
      {{ 'product-1' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
    </div>
  {%- endfor -%}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for image in product.images %}
    {% if image.alt contains 'youtube' %}
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{ image.alt }}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    {% else %}
        {% comment %} display image or whatever {% endcomment %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This code works fine on the default Shopify theme **Debut**.

I had a look at your webpage and it does have the valid iframe code. So the code you are using is working fine but the video is rendered inside the slider and is not visible to you. So just change the positioning in your code where you are outputting the IFRAME code and adjust needed CSS.